# Invalid mime type with DataWeave

Tags: xml, mule, ibm-mq, dataweave

I'm trying to create a flow in Mule ESB (Enterprise Edition) that receives a message from a queue in WMQ 7.5 (xml payload), transforms it with DataWeave (for my purposes here, to a new xml file that is the same as the old one), and then puts it back on another queue. My flow is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:wmq="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq/current/mule-wmq-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd">
    <wmq:connector (MQ configuration is here, it is not the problem) />
    <flow name="dataweaveFlow">
        <wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="I0" connector-ref="WMQ" doc:name="WMQ">
            <wmq:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
        </wmq:inbound-endpoint>
        <set-variable variableName="MULE_REPLYTO_STOP" value="true" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-payload doc:sample="empty_1.xml"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%input payload application/xml
%output application/xml
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>

        <wmq:outbound-endpoint queue="O0" connector-ref="WMQ" doc:name="WMQ">
            <wmq:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN"/>
        </wmq:outbound-endpoint>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

And my DataWeave configuration looks like this:
Input:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<empty/>
```

Transformation:

```
  %dw 1.0
%input payload application/xml
%output application/xml
---
payload
```

Now, when I run this flow, and I put a message on the queue, Mule can't process the message and continually throws exceptions, saying: "Invalid mime type application/xml", and the exception stack is 1. Invalid mime type application/xml (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.InvalidMimeTypeException) com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor:165 (null) 2. Invalid mime type application/xml (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.InvalidMimeTypeException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException) org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)

Anyway, I'm fairly new to Mule (and certainly DataWeave), and help would be appreciated! Let me know if any more details are needed.

Comment: How are you running your mule app? In studio? with maven? what mule and studio version?

Comment: Hi Shoki, I'm running my Mule app in studio without Maven -- it is Mule 3.7.2.  Additionally, I'm getting an error that says com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor: MimeType was not resolved 'application/xml' delegating to Java (I added a component to set the Mime Type to application/xml)

Comment: Shoki, I forgot to add -- I'm working with Anypoint Studio 5.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the bug being reported it was uncovered that a combination of **WMQ**, **DataWeave** and **synchronous processing strategy** was throwing this weird exception. Patch is already available, it will be fixed on future versions of the ESB but for now you may contact support and ask about **SE-3167**.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help on this matter!

Comment: Pablo! This was the great guy that helped me through the ticket from Mule 's side. @TaylorAllison I noticed that my answer was unaccepted which hurt, but this is the guy that really deserves the points anyways :)

Comment: Thank you both for the acknowledgement. This was a tricky but that are glad is fixed because it affect quite important functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

After a long conversation between Mule support and myself, this was uncovered as a bug. As of my ticket, is currently being worked on by the engineering team. This happens when your main flow processing strategy is set to `synchronous` rather than `queued asynchronous`.

Try testing this by clicking on your main flow, and setting the processing strategy to `queued asynchronous` specifically.

Note that you will not be able to use WMQ transactionality with a `queued asynchronous` processing strategy, hence my frustration with this bug.

Comment: Thanks for that info, Jaron! It always makes me feel good when I get resolution on something like this, so I know I'm not crazy!

Comment: @TaylorAllison Yeah I agree! You can imagine my frustration/relief when I realized that those few days of work were all for nothing except helping them find an internal bug..

Answer (score 0):

Add a Transformer Object to XML before the Dataweave, this will transform your Message to the correct format.

Comment: Hi Ismael, I tried to transform the payload back into XML, and Dataweave still couldn't resolve the Mime Type.

Answer (score 0):

First thing if you are getting XML from Input source suppose say WMQ connector go and set MIME type to `application/xml` . 
To set MIME type to `application/xml` right click on WMQ connector and then click on Advanced and set MIME Type : `application/xml` .

You are returning `%output application/xml` so i will suggest you to use `DOM to XML Transformer` after data weave component . I think it will work then.

Comment: Hi Utsav, I've tried setting the MIME type to application/xml, but I get a MimeType was not resolved error -- I think there's an issue with Dataweave not accepting the updated MIME type (see mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8804 for a similar bug -- it seems to be fixed, but not overall)

Comment: now what is the error you are getting , same error or different

Answer (score 0):

This issue is rather vague and the solution I found for it was even more weird.
**I simply added a "Object to String" transformer after my Data Weaver**/Transform Message, and before my WMQ outbound-endpoint, and it worked. The problem is that the Data Weaver gives an output of "com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler" **at all times**.

Do try this fix...I'm pretty sure it'll work.

Comment: Additionally, you can also configure the MIME Type of the Object to String transformer that you use. From the drop-down select "applicaiton/xml"

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned before the %input directive is not being used. It will be removed from Studio autocompletion.

The way to enforce DataWeave to use a reader is with the mimeType property or as you mentioned with a set-property as this will enforce the Mule Message to have a MimeType